# Adobe AIR runtime compatibility

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, runtime, compatibility

Is it possible that an adobe air application that runs fine with an older installed AIR runtime stops working or works buggy if it is installed on a system that has a newer version of the runtime installed?

I know by concept this should not be the case - but how is it really?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the case in some applications.

For example, the updater classes broke in my application [LinkFinderPro](http://www.linkfinderpro.com/) when they released AIR 2.7.

I haven't seen it anywhere else, really, but I had to mention this case.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is some official statement from Adobe about this but I can talk to you from my own experience:

As far as I know, Adobe runtimes, both the Flash Player and Air, have always been retrocompatible and have not had issues like the ones you describe.